# Unspecified variables although I've used them

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a site that I initially want to create an interface for SignUp and login, I created a page for Login with all the data needed to be placed, but this error appeared to me how can I handle it?

```
C:\Users\Super\Desktop\tatbekat\my-app\src\pages\Auth\login.vue
  60:8   error  'axios' is defined but never used    no-unused-vars
  81:13  error  'success' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
  84:14  error  'error' is defined but never used    no-unused-vars
```

This is the login page that contains the login form and a set of data that must be set in addition to a special login function.
login.vue:

```
 <template>
  <v-container>
    <v-layout row>
      <v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3>
        <v-card>
          <v-alert color="error" :value="error" icon="close"> </v-alert>
          <v-card-text>
            <v-container>
              <form @click="onLogin">
                <v-layout row>
                  <v-flex xs12>
                    <v-text-field
                      name="email"
                      label="Email"
                      id="email"
                      v-model="loginUser.email"
                      type="text"
                      color="#43A047"
                      required
                    >
                      {{ email }}
                    </v-text-field>
                  </v-flex>
                </v-layout>

                <v-layout row>
                  <v-flex xs12>
                    <v-text-field
                      name="password"
                      label="Password"
                      id="password"
                      v-model="loginUser.password"
                      type="password"
                      color="#43A047"
                      required
                    >
                      {{ password }}
                    </v-text-field>
                  </v-flex>
                </v-layout>

                <v-layout row>
                  <v-flex xs12>
                    <v-btn class="green darken-1 color">
                      Sign In
                    </v-btn>
                  </v-flex>
                </v-layout>
              </form>
            </v-container>
          </v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import { mapActions } from 'vuex'
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      loginUser: {
        email: "",
        password: "",
        error: false
      },
    };
  },
  method: {
    ...mapActions([
      'LOGIN'
    ]), 
    onSignIn(){
      this.$store.dispatch('LOGIN',{
        email:this.loginUser.email,
        password:this.loginUser.password
      })
      .then(success=>{
        this.$router.push("/")
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.error = true 
      })
    }
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.color {
  color: #fafafa;
}
</style>
```

And in this file, they wrote the necessary actions for the login and signup process.
user-store.js:

```
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  state: {},
  getters: {},
  mutations: {},
  actions: {
    SIGNUP: (/*{ commit },*/ payload) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios.post(`/signup` , payload)
        .then(({/*data ,*/ status }) => {
            if (status === 200){
                resolve(true)
            }
        })
        .catch(error =>{
            reject(error)
        })
      });
    },    
    LOGIN: (/*{ commit },*/ payload) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          axios.post(`/signin` , payload)
          .then(({/*data ,*/ status }) => {
              if (status === 200){
                  resolve(true)
              }
          })
          .catch(error =>{
              reject(error)
          })
        });
      },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

All the errors are coming from login.vue file:.
**axios**:  you have imported axios in login.vue but the actual axios calling is in the store file so the axios in login.vue is not used and you can delete the import.
**success**: in onSignIn method in login.vue you didn't use success in then call back so you can rewrite it like this:.
.then(() => {this.$router.push('/')}).
**error**: like the previous one you can rewrite catch block in login.vue like this:.
.catch(() => {this.error = true})